# How can I set width and height to my modal popup in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular6

I am trying to set height and width to my modal. How can I do it?

way1:

```
 <button (click)="showDialog = !showDialog" class="btn">Open</button>

  <app-dialog [(visible)]="showDialog" [height]="200" [width]="250">
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<button (click)="showDialog = !showDialog" class="btn">Close</button>
  </app-dialog>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Input property binding to add dynamic width to the dialog

```
<app-dialog [height]="200" [width]="200"   [(visible)]="showDialog">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <button (click)="showDialog = !showDialog" class="btn">Close</button>
</app-dialog>
```

**dialog.html**

```
<div [@dialog] *ngIf="visible" class="dialog" [ngStyle]="{width:width+'px',height:height+'px'}">

    <ng-content></ng-content>
    <button *ngIf="closable" (click)="close()" aria-label="Close" class="dialog__close-btn">X</button>
</div>
<div *ngIf="visible" class="overlay" (click)="close()"></div>
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rdjxwy

Comment: Chellapan: I have one more doubt..How we can show  vertical scroll on body for modal..If it's height more ?

Comment: use ngStyle to add scroll property

Comment: can you add your content inside that modal